# Starting new line in AppendAllText command

Tags: newline, powershell-2.0

Afternoon, the code I've got is as followed:

```
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+$return.Name+".txt",$return.Hash)
```

This adds into an existing text file, but at the moment it just adds information with no space, ideally I would like this to be added to a new line.

I have tried using `'n` but this doesn't seem to work, and the only information that I can find online relating to this command doesn't seem to say anything about using it with `[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText`

Is `'n` the right command to use in this situation or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure it's a tick and not a single quote:

```
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+$return.Name+".txt", $return.Hash + "`n")
```

You could also include a carriage return:

```
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+$return.Name+".txt", $return.Hash + "`r`n")
```

Or use [Environment]::NewLine

```
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("C:\Users\X\Desktop\Info\"+$return.Name+".txt", $return.Hash + ([Environment]::NewLine))
```